# Show Array in Text View

Tags: java, android, arrays, textview

I want to fill my array with random numbers, but I can't show in the `TextViewer` my array `casual[]` - help me!

```
LanciaB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int result = np2.getValue();
        int result2 = np.getValue();
        result = result == 0 ? 10 : result;

        int casual[] = new int[10];
        for(int i=0; i < result2; i++){
            casual[i] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
        }

        tv.setText(casual.toString());

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use overloaded [**Arrays#toString(int[])**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29) of Arrays which takes array as an argument.

```
 Arrays.toString(casual)
```

Comment: Thx! I used your advice but the string that is printed is not only numbers but also characters and letters ... is a printing problem or is the wrong way fill the array of random numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the elements of the array.  In Android you can do something like this:

```
tv.setText(TextUtils.join(",", casual));
```

Answer (score 0):

I used your advice but the string that is printed is not only numbers but also characters and letters ... is a printing problem (string encoding) or is the wrong way fill the array of random numbers?